# How to `#include` things from ESP-IDF?

Tags: c++, esp32, esp-idf

This is a question I have frequently. Currently I'm experiencing this confusion around the example I give below, but my question is the more general version:

How do I know what to `#include` in my C++ files when I'm looking at the ESP-IDF docs and want to use some documented method/function/class/etc?

So in today's example, I'm looking at these docs...

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/spi_flash/index.html?highlight=include%20esp_flash_encrypt#api-reference-flash-encrypt

I'm interested in using the documented `esp_flash_encryption_enabled()` function and I see that the docs say:

```
# Header File
components/bootloader_support/include/esp_flash_encrypt.h
```

So in my C++ file I enter my usage of `esp_flash_encryption_enabled()` and get a compiler error. Fair enough.

I try `#include esp_flash_encrypt.h`, no dice.
I try `#include components/bootloader_support/include/esp_flash_encrypt.h`, no dice.

How do I know, looking at the docs, what I need to import to use that code?

Comment: What do you mean by "no dice"? What error do you get? Check the path. If it works with absolute path and not with relative path, you need to set the include path properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment @kiner_shah, it pointed me in the right direction.

TL;DR

```
When the ESP-IDF docs say...

# Header File
components/bootloader_support/include/esp_flash_encrypt.h

If you want to use `esp_flash_encrypt.h` in your code, you need to 
edit your `CMakeLists.txt` file and add `bootloader_support`
(the bit after `components/` in the header path) to the 
REQUIREMENTS or PRIV_REQUIREMENTS section.
```

...here's how I got there...

You asked what I meant by `no dice.` Here's the output that I get when I try to build...

```
FAILED: esp-idf/Globals/CMakeFiles/__idf_Globals.dir/Logging.cpp.obj
ccache /opt/esp/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-12.2.0_20230208/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-g++
 -DESP_PLATFORM
 -DIDF_VER=\"v5.1-554-g25876e8f49\"
 -DSOC_MMU_PAGE_SIZE=CONFIG_MMU_PAGE_SIZE
 -D_GNU_SOURCE
 -D_POSIX_READER_WRITER_LOCKS
 -I/project/build/config
 -I/project/components/Globals/include
 -I/project/components/Dispatch/include
 -I/project/components/Wireless/include
 -I/opt/esp/idf/components/newlib/platform_include
 -I/opt/esp/idf/components/freertos/FreeRTOS
 -Kernel/include
 -I/opt/esp/idf/components/freertos/FreeRTOS-Kernel/portable/xtensa/include
 -I/opt/esp/idf/components/freertos/esp_additions/include/freertos
 -I/opt/esp/idf/components/freertos/esp_additions/include

 ... lots more paths ...

 -I/opt/esp/idf/components/lwip/lwip/src/include
 -I/opt/esp/idf/components/lwip/port/include
 -I/opt/esp/idf/components/lwip/port/freertos/include
 -I/opt/esp/idf/components/lwip/port/esp32xx/include
 -I/opt/esp/idf/components/lwip/port/esp32xx/include/arch
 -I/opt/esp/idf/components/esp_timer/include
 -I/opt/esp/idf/components/spi_flash/include
 -mlongcalls -Wno-frame-address  -fdiagnostics-color=always -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
 -Wall -Werror=all -Wno-error=unused-function -Wno-error=unused-variable -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable
 -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-enum-conversion
 -gdwarf-4 -ggdb -Og -fmacro-prefix-map=/project=. -fmacro-prefix-map=/opt/esp/idf=/IDF
 -fstrict-volatile-bitfields -fno-jump-tables -fno-tree-switch-conversion -DconfigENABLE_FREERTOS_DEBUG_OCDAWARE=1
 -std=gnu++2b -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -MD -MT esp-idf/Globals/CMakeFiles/__idf_Globals.dir/Logging.cpp.obj
 -MF esp-idf/Globals/CMakeFiles/__idf_Globals.dir/Logging.cpp.obj.d
 -o esp-idf/Globals/CMakeFiles/__idf_Globals.dir/Logging.cpp.obj -c /project/components/Globals/Logging.cpp
/project/components/Globals/Logging.cpp:7:10: fatal error: esp_flash_encrypt.h: No such file or directory
    7 | #include "esp_flash_encrypt.h"  // for esp_flash_encryption_enabled()
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

(I formatted this nicely adding carriage returns... the compiler obnoxiously just puts all that in one big long line...)

But I looked into all those paths and didn't see the path to `components/bootloader_support/include/` where that file I want lives.

In the component folder that I'm working with, in ESP-IDF, you always have a `CMakeLists.txt` file, and here's what that looks like right now...

```
idf_component_register(
  SRCS
    "Logging.cpp"
    "Globals.cpp"
  INCLUDE_DIRS
    "include"
    "../Dispatch/include"
    "../Wireless/include"
    "../Globals/include"

  # use `PRIV_REQUIRES` for idf requirements used here but not subsequently imported by other components
  PRIV_REQUIRES
    esp_timer
    spi_flash

  # use `REQUIRES` for idf requirements used here that ARE subsequently imported by other components
  # REQUIRES
)
```

I never fully understood what those `PRIV_REQUIRES` and `REQUIRES` sections were about. But when I edited the `PRIV_REQUIRES` section to be...

```
  PRIV_REQUIRES
    esp_timer
    spi_flash
    bootloader_support
```

...and recompiled, it succeeded. Obnoxiously this didn't show me much. So I added `#include "file_that_does_not_exist.h"` in my C++ file, and now I get my error again, but this time in my list of paths, I also see the following!

```
...giant list of paths...
-I/opt/esp/idf/components/bootloader_support/include 
-I/opt/esp/idf/components/bootloader_support/bootloader_flash/include 
...more compiler options...
```

So apparently that's what ESP-IDF is doing with that. If you want to import a header that's in a component in the ESP-IDF you have to list that component in your CMakeLists.txt file under `REQUIRES` or `PRIV_REQUIRES` and ESP-IDF will make sure to add in the paths that are relevant to that component.

Sweet. A little more clarity achieved!